# Avoid injecting concrete database context class to controller

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am using Entity Framework Core for MySql with Database first approach.

After scaffolding the database, it generates the context class: sakilaContext.cs(sakila is the built-in database/scheme in MySql, I use it for playing around).

I have my database injected in Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);
        var connectionString = @"server=localhost;port=1123;user=root;password=xxx;database=sakila";
        services.AddDbContext<sakilaContext>(options => options.UseMySql(connectionString));
    }
```

In my api controller, I do it like this:

```
private sakilaContext dbCtx;

public SakilaController(sakilaContext dbContext)
{
    dbCtx = dbContext;
}
```

Just wonder,

1. is it wrong to inject a concrete implementation in this case??
2. If it is, how can I just inject an interface rather than inject a concrete implementation?

Thanks

Comment: 1. I think no, there's nothing wrong with it because a generic `dbcontext` will not contain your properties, so you can't do much with it

Comment: @KienChu huh, I kinda agree with you. But if we inject a concrete class, does it defeat the DI purpose?

Comment: DI has more benefits than just wiring the abstraction and implementation, it helps reducing the complexity of your dependency graph, helps you controlling the lifetime of the object automatically, etc

Comment: I don't think it's wrong to inject a concrete implementation, specially in this case it's the database provider. I mean having a DI and interface for the database provider is nice, but how often do you / would you switch database providers along the project? Usually a kind of database providers will be selected and would last for the entire life of a project. Now to avoid having the concrete class everywhere in your code, you can write a factory to generate the dbContext and inject its interface, or use the MediatR @Darren mentioned.

Comment: @DavidLiang then how are we going to test the controller ? since we have that controller coupled with the database provider.

Comment: @KienChu thanks, I agree with those ideas. but how to test the controller since it couples with the database provider.

Comment: @Franva: You still can mock the DbContext and IDbSets. Have you read https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/fundamentals/testing/mocking#testing-non-query-scenarios?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is it wrong to inject a concrete implementation in this case??

It *depends*.  If you're writing a multi-tier application with separated concerns (business logic, validation, authorization) or are you writing a 5 page application to display misc information for a limited number of users?

I've done exactly that for small, mostly readonly, applications because there are only small changes and I don't need to [Over design and architect the solution](https://www.codemag.com/Article/0603101/Bloated-Designs-Over-Architecting-and-Refactoring).

> If it is, how can I just inject an interface rather than inject a concrete implementation?

Sure, however at some point a class will need a dbcontext, which could be DI'd or created by the object that needs it.  If you do abstract away the Data Access into a separate class/interface, I wouldn't recommend DI (to inject the context into the concrete data access) because that concrete type will be tighly coupled to EF.  Meaning if you decided to switch to Dapper, NHibernate or some other ORM you'll have to rewrite all the methods anyway.

A quick and dirty way (for small/learning experiences, I would not ever recommend this for large million user systems) to abstract away the `DbContext` is as simple as:

```
public interface IUserDA
{
  IQueryable<User> Users { get; }
}

public class MyDbContext : IUserDA
{
  public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

  IQueryable<User> IUserDA.Users
  {
     get
     {
        return Users;  // references the DbSet
     }
  }

}
```

Now your MyDbContext implements an interface that is not coupled to Entity Framework.

> But if we inject a concrete class, does it defeat the DI purpose?

Depends on your purpose.  What exactly are you looking to achieve by using DI?  Are you actually going to write real unit tests?  Do you honestly see yourself changing or having multiple instances of the interfaces for multiple installation/tenants?

Comment: very true, normally a project will stick with one chosen database. but when it comes to testing, how are we going to test a controller coupled with a concrete database context class?

Comment: That's why I asked what your purpose for DI was.

Answer (score 1):

I would not suggest abstracting Entity Framework out as it is already an abstraction itself (you can swap out DB providers from, let's say, SQL Server to PostgreSQL without your consuming classes knowing). I would not suggest injecting your context into your controller either.

What I like to do, and I would suggest that you look into this yourself to see if it is suitable, is to adopt the [Command Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern), leveraging the amazing Jimmy Bogard's libraries [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) and [MediatR](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR).

To give you a basic example of how a controller might look using such an architectural design choice:

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SomeTypeController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;
    private readonly IMapper mapper;

    public SomeTypeController(IMediator mediator, IMapper mapper)
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;
        this.mapper = mapper;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<SomeTypeContract>>> GetAll(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var result = await mediator.Send(new GetAllSomeTypeRequest(), cancellationToken);
        return Ok(mapper.Map<IEnumerable<SomeTypeContract>>(result));
    }
}
```

I really like this because now your controllers act as routers to business logic. They are blissfully unaware of what exactly is going on under the hood (or how it is going on).

To get to the heart of your question:

> Is it wrong to inject a concrete implementation in this case??

The answer to this is a bit of an opinionated one, but many believe it to not only be an acceptable choice, but the right one. At some point in time, in order to make actual DB queries, you **will** want to have knowledge of your DBContext.

By abstracting it out, you will only cause yourself pain by writing hundreds of different methods for querying your data in different ways, doing all sorts of `selects` and `includes`. Either that or you will have 'chunky' methods that return far more data than you actually need.

By having concrete knowledge of your DBContext (likely in your request handlers if you go with the Command Pattern) you get full control over how your data is acquired, allowing for query optimisation as well as enforcing a separation of concerns.

Disclaimer: I brought up the above-mentioned libraries because they are wonderful and helpful, but I know many people look down on their inclusion in an answer. I would just like to make it clear that they are in no way a requirement to carry out the Command Pattern, but if you're going to adopt it, why reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I like the mediator pattern as well, and am a fan of Jimmy. But I don't think that's what @Franva is asking. Even with the mediator pattern, the `DbContext` would still need to be injected later in the pipeline, either in the handler or the repository.

Comment: Thanks for that, I got so caught up with what I wrote that I forgot the question at hand. I've updated my post!

Comment: I don't think there is ever anything wrong with including Libraries as long as you disclose if you are in any way associated with them.

Comment: That's fair, though I am not sure that everyone agrees on that. Also I am not in any way affiliated with Jimmy Bogard, as much as I wish I were!

Comment: thanks @DarrenRuane, I have a project with MediatR and Autofac, but still I need to inject the concrete dbContext class in handlers if I gonna use it there. so I guess the conclusion is it depends case by case. In a small or even middle scale project, it is find to inject a concrete class. In the large project, better to write interface for those concrete classes and inject it to where needed.

Comment: Yes, your handlers would still need the concrete dependency, but what I've done in the past is only inject the `DBSets` in rather than the whole `DBContext`. You could even inject these as `IQueryables` as @Erik Philips suggested. In most cases, you do not *need* the whole `DBContext`, especially when using RequestHandlers as they usually just run queries or commands on the `DBSets`.

Comment: If you decide to do this, then another thing you should know is I delegated the responsibility of saving the changes in my `DBContext` to an [Action Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2). This meant that all my handlers needed was indeed the `DBSets` and they did not have to worry about saving changes. This is something that Jimmy Bogard has outlined in his [Contoso University Core](https://github.com/jbogard/ContosoUniversityCore/blob/master/src/ContosoUniversityCore/Infrastructure/DbContextTransactionFilter.cs) project.

Comment: I am currently trying to do this, but when I inject the DBContext to my Mediatr Handler, it works but only for the first request, the second request fails with the message: The connection does not support MultipleActiveResultSets.

I registered my IAppDbContext Interface as Scoped...